# How to access SVG element with javascript/typescript with same ids?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svg

How can I access different SVG elements individually which use the same id for their design.

for eg:-

```
<g id="A1">
    <g id="light_on"><other tags></g>
</g>
<g id="A2">
    <g id="light_on"></g>
</g>
```

I want to access only the element which is contained under A1 but not the one under A2. In the above example I just want hide the design of the light_on so that the image looks like the light is off, but I don't want that design to hide in the element under A2.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#A1').querySelector('#light_on')`

Comment: Please give separate ids else its gonna be a problem. You can however give the same class to both of them.

Comment: It's invalid to have duplicate ids, don't do that. Use a class and select all elements with the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access it with the parent's selector to differentiate between the two.

```
document.querySelector('#A1 #light_on')
document.querySelector('#A2 #light_on')
```

However, I would recommend against using same ids for multiple elements in DOM.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t3mb0qtf/ Press F12 in Chrome for the console output.